# Sorting and filtering nodes in Neo4j spatial query

Tags: lucene, neo4j, neo4j-spatial

Is it possible to filter nodes in Neo4j by geographical distance and by node properties, returning the nodes some order other then their distance (like a timestamp).  I can do one or the other using either the standard lucene based indexing and the neo4j geo layer, but I can't seem to marry the two to provide a comprehensive lookup.  Any ideas on how to achieve this would be really appreciated.  Many thanks, James.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, [see this blog post](https://structr.org/blog/distance-queries-with-neo4j-spatial).

You have to have a `LayerNodeIndex` in place, which you've added your nodes to:

```
LayerNodeIndex layerIndex = new LayerNodeIndex("layerIndex", graphDb, config);
```

Then you just query the index:

```
IndexHits hits  = index.query(LayerNodeIndex.WITHIN_DISTANCE_QUERY, params);

Double coords = new Double[]{ 10.415039d, 51.151786d };
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();

params.put(LayerNodeIndex.POINT_PARAMETER, coords.toArray());
params.put(LayerNodeIndex.DISTANCE_IN_KM_PARAMETER, dist);

IndexHits hits  = index.query(LayerNodeIndex.WITHIN_DISTANCE_QUERY, params);
```

Comment: That's great thanks for your help, but how do you then filter by another property, and sort the results by another property say timestamp?